# Query that excludes some ids

Tags: datomic

I'd like to write a query that provides a list of entity ids that will be filtered out.

The following query still returns everything in the id list

```
(d/q '[:find (pull ?e [:db/id
                       :user/first-name])
       :in $ ?account [?id ...]
       :where [?e :user/account ?account]
              (not [(= ?e ?id)])]
     db 18625726974632500 [40809473576669559 47437329668874807])
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I could do this by using a scalar input rather than a collection input:

```
(d/q '[:find (pull ?e [:db/id
                       :user/first-name])
       :in $ ?account ?ids
       :where [?e :user/account ?account]
              (not [(contains? ?ids ?e)])]
     db 18625726974632500 #{40809473576669559 47437329668874807})
```